# Мало того(,) что

Tags: пунктуация

**Мало того(,) что она банальная, так еще и глупая**

Answer (score 3):

Обычно подобные ("двоякочленимые") составные союзы не членятся, если стоят в абсолютном начале предложения. Это естественно, иначе получается, что первач часть такого союза само по себе составляет основное предложение. 
Поэтому надо увидеть очень сильное логическое ударение, чтобы расчленить такой союз в начале предложения.
Я бы поостерегся. Мне даже пример с "Грамоты"  (из Визбора) кажется "авторским", я там запятой не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

МАЛО ТОГО(,) ЧТО - это составной союз.

Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «мало того что», выделяются с двух сторон знаками препинания. При этом первый знак препинания может ставиться либо перед составным союзом, либо между его частями (перед словом «что»).

Условия расчленения: перед составным союзом имеется отрицание «не»; перед составным союзом есть усилительные, ограничительные и другие частицы, вводные слова, наречия; 
первая часть составного союза входит в ряд однородных членов предложения или параллельных конструкций; автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение.

Мало того что пойдешь в посмешище – найдется щелкопер, бумагомарака, в комедию тебя вставит. Н. Гоголь. Но это было очень трудно: мало того что стебель кололся со всех сторон, даже через платок, которым я завернул руку, – он был так страшно крепок, что я бился с ним минут пять, по одному разрывая волокна. Л. Толстой,  Мало того, что она имела свое собственное и довольно приличное снаряжение, она и неплохо каталась. Ю. Визбор. ((С "Грамоты")

Из всех условий возможно лишь наличие логического ударения, так что решать Вам: расчленять союз или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Я не поставила бы запятую между частями союза "мало того что", так как этому препятствует элемент ***"так ещё и"***. 
ПО ФОРМЕ конструкция ***"Мало того что она банальная, так еще и глупая"*** - это сложное предложение. Соединяет простые предложения ***двухместный союз*** "мало того что... ещё и", употреблённый к тому же с частицей ***так***.  А если есть такое продолжение союза МАЛО ТОГО ЧТО, запятая между его частями не ставится, а ставится только перед второй частью двухместного союза, в данном случае перед "так ещё и". Заметьте, в предложениях с "Грамоты", предоставленных Ларf, на месте предполагаемого продолжения союза стоит тире, а сам союз не расчленяется. А в примере "***Мало того, что*** она имела свое собственное и довольно приличное снаряжение, она и неплохо каталась" продолжения союза нет и союз расчленён запятой.

***Ср. : Мало того, что она банальная, [она]  глупая.***